# Decodable swift value without brackets

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

How to decode id with Decodable

I have JSON like: id  (without brackets)

my code

```
struct Id:Codable {
  var id:UInt
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full JSON? I am having a hard time understanding what your problem is

Comment: @CodeDifferent https://Drygan.tinytake.com/sf/MjkxNTc3MV84NzQ2Njg4

Comment: It cannot be decoded with Decodable, since you don't have {key: value}, you have just a number there, so access the number directly when you receive the response.